# AWS S3 Bucket allows Google to index documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-search

I have PDF documents in AWS S3 buckets that are appearing in Google search results. How can I prevent Google from providing the URL's to these documents in search results?

I have tried to add a robots file in the root of the buckets holding these docs but it is still occurring.

Any help appreciated.

Edit to add the content of robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Is the `robots.txt` file publicly accessible (downloadable from a browser at `http://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/robots.txt`)?  Show the content of your robots file?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Show the contents of your robots.txt file, please.

Comment: Added the contents of robots.txt to original post. This is saved in the root of the bucket

Comment: On the bucket > Permissions > Manage public permissions >  Everyone: Read/Read. 
If I were to remove Read would this then remove the "make public" setting on all files? Could this prevent the bucket indexing?

Comment: That will depend on whether the individual files are *also* marked with the `public-read` ACL.  You didn't mention that you didn't want the content to be public at all... I assumed you just didn't want it in search results.

Comment: The files must remain public and are individually configured as public I wondered if the bucket policy above would override every file. The Listing of them is what I need to restrict. The old documentation for AWS gives the options [List], [Upload/Delete], [View Permissions], [Edit Permissions]. The new AWS interface doesn't give those options, only [Read], [Write].

Comment: That's a very good point.  Scratch my previous comment, the objects are made public by either object-level ACL or *bucket policy*.  This screen is not bucket policy, but rather *bucket ACL*.  Turning off "read" here should be the equivalent of turning off "list" in the old console.  If listing is enabled, then checking `http://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` in the browser will give you a list of your objects. If disabled, you'll get Access Denied.

Comment: Yes, the list is now displaying the bucket contents in in XML format. Could Google be crawling this and indexing from here? Also, is it certain that removing "Read" from "Object access" in the Bucket ACL will not affect the contents?

Comment: The documents are still accessible on Google. Another bucket already had the Everyone group deactivated on "Read". Any other ideas?